# How to allow django view in nginx with PWA at /

Tags: django, nginx, progressive-web-apps, nginx-location, nginx-config

I'm trying to setting up nginx to my PWA app with django backend.
My django backend has some views to pdf reports on /export route.
My PWA app (Vue) runs on /. I'm getting a blank page when access to /export. The blank page is trying to response from PWA, but when I reload with Shift (⇧) it loads the pdf report.

Here is my nginx server config:

```
server {
  server_name               awesome.app;

  root                      /home/awesomeapp/pwa;

  location /api/ {
    include                 proxy_params;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP                  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For            $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/awesomeapp/awesome-backend/awesome.sock;
  }

  location /export/ {
    include                 proxy_params;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP                  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For            $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/awesomeapp/awesome-backend/awesome.sock;
  }

  location / {
    index index.html;
  }
}
```

Any idea how to setting up nginx to allow the access to the pdf report generated by django?
Secondly, django backend also has a dashboard app (no pwa) but nginx does not allows to access it (only with shift(⇧)).

Answer (score 0):

OP here.
I'm using workbox (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox) to simplify service workers management.
Workbox allows exclude url paths in pwa routing (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/v4/workbox.routing). Black lists solve my problem.